# Android: Uploading multiple string records to Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, arrays

I am working on a app where I would like to upload a string array. Code as follows:

### Code:

```
    upload_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.upload_list);
    Utilities.custom_toast(this, ""+upload_list.length, "");
    ParseObject database = new ParseObject("table_name");
    for (int m = 0; m < upload_list.length; m++) 
    {       
        database.put("name_full",   upload_list[m]);
        database.saveInBackground();
    }
```

### Question:

The above string array has 90 items. After going through the above code, 1 new row is added to the table, and keep refreshing the table in Parse, different strings picked from the above string array is reflected in the row.

I would like instead inserting 90 new rows to the table.

How could that be fixed? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want NEW ROW in the loop, move the new ParseObject :

```
 ParseObject database;
... 
    for (int m = 0; m < upload_list.length; m++) 
    {  
        database = new ParseObject("table_name");     
        database.put("name_full",   upload_list[m]);
        database.saveInBackground();
    }
```